# LINQ to XML query doesn't return any results

Tags: c#, xml, list, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to query an XML tree and store the resulting element values in a list of objects similar to [this example](http://www.codearsenal.net/2012/07/c-sharp-load-xml-using-xlinq.html).

The issue is that no matter what I try, I can't populate the list. I don't have any errors, I just have an empty list. I'm almost certain that my query is set up wrong, but I'm new to LINQ and I can't figure out where I've gone wrong. Here's the class I'm using:

```
public class Individual
{
    public string field1 { get; set; }
    public string field2 { get; set; }
    public bool field3 { get; set; }
}
```

And here are my vars and query:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(new System.IO.StringReader(MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().OuterXml));

xmlDoc.Descendants()
    .Attributes()
    .Where(x => x.IsNamespaceDeclaration)
    .Remove();

List<Individual> individualList =
    (
        from el in xmlDoc.Root.Elements("myFields").Descendants("Individual")
        select new Individual
        {
            field1 = (string)el.Element("field1"),
            field2 = (string)el.Element("field2"),
            field3 = (bool)el.Element("field3")
        }
    ).ToList();
```

And this is the XML doc:

```
<?mso-infoPathSolution solutionVersion="1.0.0.31" productVersion="15.0.0" PIVersion="1.0.0.0" href="file:///C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\InfoPath\Designer4\991d50f99c274f7c\manifest.xsf" ?>
<?mso-application progid="InfoPath.Document" versionProgid="InfoPath.Document.4"?>
<myFields xml:lang="en-us" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2021-02-26T15:29:19">
  <DirectReportsList>
    <Individual>
      <field1>foo</field1>
      <field2>bar</field2>
      <field3>true</field3>
    </Individual>
  </DirectReportsList>
  <Current_UserID></Current_UserID>
  <Current_UserName></Current_UserName>
</myFields>
```

Comment: @Crowcoder well, I have tried that to some extent. But I attempted that prior to adding the remove namespace declaration bit. Though obviously that removes all but one namespace. I’d prefer to not have any namespace to deal with at all; why isn’t my code removing that last namespace?

Comment: No, your code is not actually removing the namespace. You can see that if you debug. Another problem is that `myFields` IS the root, so you cannot navigate from root to myFields to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is looking for a `myFields` element under the root, but that is the root so nothing is being found.

This what you can do:

```
XNamespace ns ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2021-02-26T15:29:19";
        
List<Individual> individualList =
    (
        from el in xmlDoc.Root.Descendants(ns + "Individual")
        select new Individual
        {
            field1 = (string)el.Element(ns + "field1"),
            field2 = (string)el.Element(ns +"field2"),
            field3 = (bool)el.Element(ns +"field3")
        }
    ).ToList();
}
```

If you really don't want to deal with namespaces you can use LocalName of elements but then it is fragile to unexpected xml content.

> Update

I just looked at the example you linked to. It doesn't work, the author posted bad code.

Comment: Thanks! I tried your suggestion and indeed, there’s an error. Is this code salvageable or should I scrap it?

Comment: Its fine if that's what you need

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re saying. If the code doesn’t work, how is that what I need?

Comment: The code in my answer works, can you use that?

Comment: Oh, I understand now. No, the error I was referring to was thrown while using the code in your answer; `Value cannot be null.`

Comment: @ARich oh, ok. Not sure what that is about. It works for me, [here is a linqpad script](http://share.linqpad.net/xms3hm.linq)

Comment: I'm an idiot. I forgot to include the namespace in the field elements like you showed. So the query was returning all `null`s -- the bool field was throwing the `Value cannot be null` error. Thanks again for the help!